# Two spaces after every full stop in paragraph using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I put two spaces after every full stop in a paragraph using CSS?

Comment: why don't you just put 2 spaces where you want them directly in your html?

Comment: Aside from `::first-letter` and `::first-line`, everything else in CSS wants to work with elements - whether they be identified by `id`, class or element type. Full stops aren't elements.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The web is its own medium; print conventions shouldn't be carried over wholesale purely for the sake of it, IMO.

Comment: Also why is there a `www.google.com` in your question? If anything you should be putting that in your browser's address bar, not here.

Comment: @kennypu - Because in HTML the browser automatically replaces all double spaces with a single space.  To force a double space in HTML, you end up having to insert &nbsp;&nbsp; (or just add one &nbsp after an actual space).  It gets ugly in the code, and I too am wanting a CSS way to force double-space at the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 11):

Ah, the old "two-spaces-after-a-period" meme rears its ugly head again.

Two spaces after a period is something that pertains to the typewriter world, or the monospaced font world. We moved beyond it long ago, starting with TeX or even before. The point is not to have one or two space characters after a period, but to have a pleasing amount of space there. Algorithms like TeX go to great length to do so. The algorithms in modern web browsers are still primitive by comparison, but are starting to do better. Consider the following:

[image]

You'll see that the space after the period is (slightly) greater than the inter-word space, as it should be.

What about the case of justification? You'd hope the browser would put the extra space between sentences, in preference to putting it between words. And that's what happens:

[image]

Anyway, so you want more fine-grained control, to realize your own typographical vision on your web pages. The following has four `&nbsp;` characters between the sentences:

[image]

You could also use spaces of different widths from Unicode to get just the amount of space you want (see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29)).

So is there any way to do this automatically? CSS has a `word-spacing` property, but no `sentence-spacing` property (actually, it's not that easy to figure out what a "sentence" is, even in English, and less so in other languages). Of course, putting more spaces in your HTML is not going to do a thing, since HTML treats any run of white space as a single space. So you're going to have to write some code, or find a plug-in, which traverses the text in your page and inserts markup. Or, add a plug-in or something to your CMS to spit out code which is marked up appropriately. Your alternatives for doing so are:

1. Add `&nbsp;` or a combination of different-width Unicode spaces.
2. As another poster suggested, use `span` tags with `margin`.
3. As a variant on the above, use a `<span class="sentence">` element, with a CSS rules like `.sentence::after { content: "\2002"; }`, where 2002 is the "en-space". This results in:

[image]

However, the bottom line is that the web is not a typographical environment, notwithstanding the many worthy efforts to nudge it in that direction. Depending on your goals, you might consider creating your documents in a high-end document preparation environment, and publishing them as PDFs, for example.

Comment: This is beautiful. Over the top, roundabout way of saying "you can by jumping through a bunch of fire hoops" maybe, but beautiful nonetheless.

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2018/05/04/one-space-between-each-sentence-they-said-science-just-proved-them-wrong-2/

Comment: Not just typewriter anymore. Science (ya I know) proved we read it better.

Answer (score 4):

The two spaces concept after a sentence is not "ugly" - in fact, it's just the opposite.  Because of modern font kerning as well as the variety of fonts that Web browsers now support, it's sometimes very difficult to determine if a sentence has ended or if there is simply a word that is abbreviated that requires a period, not to mention a look of constant run-on.  With 'fat' letters beginning a sentence, such as an upper-case "W", it can appear as though there is actually no space at all.  Adding an additional space after a sentence provides readers with clear breaks. However, I get it that it would be quite difficult to create CSS that could "understand" what a sentence is so that it would automatically insert an additional space after each.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your full stop in a span-tag and give it some CSS attributes, like "margin-right: 5px;", if it's only the appearance you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can only be done if you put your full stop to a tag, like `<span>`. For example :

`www<span>.</span>google<span>.</span>com`

Then the css is :

```
span:after{
   content : "  "; /*two spaces*/
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't do anything different than would a single space, nor a hundred.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

```
<span>.</span>
```

And/or add a class...

And then in the css

```
span { margin-right: .5ch;}
```

ch stands for character (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units .5ch is meant if you leave a regular space after your period, which I'd do if only to keep your eyes.

You might want to format your sentences into separate lines